# UILabel won't update

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, uilabel

I need enlightenment with my view controllers. The **first view controller** has a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. The `UIButton` leads to the **second view controller**.

The **second view controller** is a `UITableView`. Everything in this view is done programmatically including the `UINavigationBar`, `UINavigationItem`, and the `UIBarButtonItem`. It has NO `UINavigationController`.

So once a user selects a currency from the list, it should update the `UILabel` in the **first view controller**. But it won't.

first view controller .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CurrencyListViewController.h"

@interface InformationViewController : UIViewController <CurrencyListViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *currencyLabel;

- (IBAction)currencyButton;

@end
```

first view controller .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createCurrencyButton];

    [self createAcceptDeclineButton];

    [self createCurrencyLabel];
}

- (IBAction)currencyButton
{
    CurrencyListViewController *currencyView = [[CurrencyListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrencyListViewController" bundle:nil];
    currencyView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    currencyView.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:currencyView animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)createCurrencyLabel
{
    currencyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 40.0)];

    currencyLabel.hidden = NO;
    currencyLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    currencyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [currencyLabel setEnabled:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:currencyLabel];
}

- (void)currencySelected: (NSString *)currencySelected
{
    currencyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currencySelected];

    NSLog(@"Current currency is %@", currencyLabel.text);
}
```

second view controller .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CurrencyListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)currencySelected: (NSString *)currencySelected;

@end

@interface CurrencyListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    id<CurrencyListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

second view controller .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Currency"];
    UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cancel"
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self
                                                           action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem;

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView = tableView;

    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
    [self showCurrencies];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayOfCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    InformationViewController *informationViewController = [[InformationViewController alloc] init];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(currencySelected:)]) {
        informationViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

        [_delegate currencySelected:[arrayOfCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"The user selects %@", [arrayOfCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }

    [self presentViewController:informationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am able to output:

```
2013-06-05 00:16:58.731 Testing[7056:c07] Current currency is AOA: Angolan Kwanza
2013-06-04 19:08:27.222 Testing[3613:c07] 2013-06-05 00:16:58.732 Testing[7056:c07] The user selects AOA: Angolan Kwanza
```

But the `UILabel` in my **first view controller** will **NOT**.

Comment: Where is your "first view controller"?  Where do you create it?  Where is the pointer to it?

Comment: I see something that has the same name as the "first view controller", but it's created after everything else, and it's `currencySelected` method is never invoked.  Rather, the *different* _delegate method is invoked.

Comment: In fact, I don't see anywhere where _delegate is set, so likely you're making a call on a nil pointer.

Comment: You are presenting `InformationViewController ` and updating the label of `_delegate` object. So how can will you see the `UILabel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are presenting informationViewController again? dismiss the Current ViewController, which is CurrencyListViewController and do the currencySelected function

Should look like this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[_delegate currencySelected:[arrayOfCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realized I presented informationViewController again.